# How do I install OpenStack on a minimal machine set for testing and development?

Tags: cloud, openstack

Looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure, I see three different ways to do this and the third option "Install Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure from packages: the hard way" seems like the option for me, but not even basic  steps are included in the document.

The first option doesn't seem to fit my scenario because I don't want to run a live image because I have a couple machines I'd like to use if possible--one beefy for VMs and one wimpy for infrastructure services (if OpenStack will even work that way, maybe I'm confusing it with Eucalyptus)

I don't think I can use the second option because I don't have 10+ machines to set up MAAS, though that does sound pretty cool.

Is this a reasonable scenario? Where can I find at least a basic set of steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [DevStack](http://devstack.org/), a shell script to build an OpenStack environment on a single machine for testing and development.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want-There are also docs that describe how to get a bit more complicated and use a couple machines.  Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448987/deploy-app-on-openstack-deployed-locally-on-single-machine