# Deploy app on OpenStack deployed locally on single machine

Tags: 12.04, server, application-development, cloud

I have deployed `OpenStack` using `DevStack` on single **Ubuntu 12.04** machine running all services.

I actually have to develop a Private **Cloud Document Management System**

Now, I want to know that how do I develop a simple, simplest app, preferably in `PHP` on `OpenStack` cloud?

Can I develop it using `PHP-OpenCloud`? (Some told me that it is *only for OpenStack deployed on RackSpace Cloud*)?

Or can I develop using `OpenStack Heat`? Do I need to create a **VM** and *lauch instance* before I start with `Heat`?